# Getting list of emails in google contacts email directory from Google People API using Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-people-api

How do I get `People.searchDirectoryPeople()` working? This is what I have got:

```
People.searchDirectoryPeople().setQuery("Justin");
```

I was able to get https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/apps-script working in apps-script but nothing else so far.

My goal is to search through the directory, either by email or by name (preferably learn how to do both) - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The Google Apps Script advanced services are basically wrappers for their REST API counterparts. So typically, you'd need to look up the REST documentation to figure out how to properly leverage API endpoints.

However, in this case, the documentation for the `searchDirectoryPeople` endpoint does not explain query syntax. Fortunately, query syntax is common to many Google APIs, and is documented under the Drive API. The following links should help you to get moving in the right direction:

https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/searchDirectoryPeople
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files

There are relevant code sample available in the second link under the `Node.js` tab.

Also, be sure to take advantage of the Apps Script editor's code completion features to figure out which params you can pass to an endpoint.

Comment: Thank you! Real quick about the first paragraph: Are there any other coding languages/programs I should learn to take full advantage of the Google Apps Script / Advanced Services?

Also, code completion features? The autofill, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple script to search the directory:

```
function searchDirectory() {
  var results = People.People.searchDirectoryPeople({ 
    query : "Tom",
    readMask: "names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers",
    sources: "DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE"
  });

  Logger.log("results: " + JSON.stringify(results, null, 0));

  results.people?.forEach(person => Logger.log(person.names?.map(name => name.displayName) + ", " + 
                                              person.emailAddresses?.map(email => email.value) + ", " + 
                                              person.phoneNumbers?.map(phone => phone.value)));
}
```

The first log will output the raw results object, the loop will then go over each person in the results and log their name, emails & phones.